# avoid dialog box when netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect"); is called

Tags: javascript, mozilla, xpcom

Hi i got to create.write,read a local file within the javascript using XPCom. For that i have included the below line at the beginning of javascript.

```
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");
```

But when the above script executes, a dialog box appears saying

```
  **Internet security** 

   A script from "file://" is requesting enhanced abilities
   that are UNSAFE and could be used to compromise your machine or data:
   Run or install software on your machine
   Allow these abilities only if you trust this source 
  to be free of viruses or malicious programs.
      ______       _______       
     | Deny |     | Allow |
     --------     ---------
```

But i dont want the dialog box to be appeared.How can i avoid it?. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. It would be a major security problem to allow a web page to gain extra JavaScript privileges (full access to XPCOM in this case) without an explicit authorization by the user.